# How to avoid escaping "&" when outputing XML for XLST to HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating an XML file that I convert to HTML using an XSL transform in c++. The output method of the transform is html. I am trying to ouput unicode characters in hex format. For example, I would like to ouput "&#x00cd" to the XML file. If I use

```
XmlDocument ^doc = gcnew XmlDocument();
doc->Load("XmlFile.xml");
XmlNode^ currNode = doc->DocumentElement->FirstChild;   
currNode = currNode->NextSibling;
currNode->InnerText = L"&#x00CD;";
```

then the output XML using default settings

```
XmlWriter^ writer = XmlWriter::Create("XmlFileOut.xml", settings);
doc->Save(writer);
```

looks like

```
<node>&amp;#x00CD;</node>
```

then when I do the xml to html transform, instead of the charcter I want in the font of choice, I get

```
<p>Your symbol is (<span style="font-family:MyFont">&amp;#x00CD;</span>)</p>
```

which, of course, shows up in the browser as

```
You symbol is &#x00CD;
```

If I use

```
currNode->InnerXML = L"&#x00CD;";
```

then the output xml contains the actual character

```
<node>Í</node>
```

and the resulting HTML works OK too

```
<p>Your symbol is (<span style="font-family:MyFont">Í</span>)</p>
```

which produces the correct character symbol in the browser.

BUT, I want the XML output AND the HTML output to use the hex unicode value

```
&#x00CD;
```

instead of the actual character 'Í'

```
<node>&#x00CD;</node>
```

for the XML and

```
<p>Your symbol is (<span style="font-family:MyFont">&#x00CD;</span>)</p>
```

for the HTML, so that I can more easily use an XSL transform to create an RTF file from the resulting HTML. (I need both HTML and RTF.)

I know this must be dirt simple but I have busted my pic on this.

Comment: If you want to "use an XSL transform to create an RTF" then I don't understand why you need character references. XSLT as XML has full Unicode support so should have no problems with input like `<p>Your symbol is (<span style="font-family:MyFont">Í</span>)</p>`, as long as the XML parser used to process it knows the encoding used.

Comment: Yup, I can see that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use XSLT to create HTML with XslCompiledTransform where any non-ASCII characters are escaped as character references then use `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="us-ascii"/>`, that way your sample

```
<p>
            Your symbol is (<span style="font-family:MyFont">Í</span>)
          </p>
```

is serialized as

```
<p>
        Your symbol is (<span style="font-family:MyFont">&#xCD;</span>)
      </p>
```

when using XslCompiledTransform with C# as

```
        XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
        proc.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt");

        proc.Transform("XMLFile1.xml", "Result1.html");
```

You will have to transcode that to C++/CLI but the approach should be clear.

Comment: Yes, this works to produce an HTML file with the hex Unicode value even though the XML has the special char. Thanks.

Comment: And I can do essentially the same thing to get the output XML to show the hex char code by setting the XMLWriterSettings.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII ... in case anyone else out there is interested.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise looks faulty.  Having the HTML refer to the character using a hexadecimal numeric character reference is not going to make a blind bit of difference to the ease of writing an XSLT transformation to produce an RTF file from the (X)HTML:  the difference between characters present in the input in 'literal form' (if we may call it that) and characters present by virtue of a numeric character reference is not visible in the data model used by XSLT.

If you were creating the RTF with sed, or some other non-XML-aware tool, or with an XML tool that used a data model in which the difference between `a` and `&#x0061;` and `&#97;` is visible (I don't know of any, but such tools  are imaginable), then your best bet would be to specify an output encoding of US-ASCII, which will induce the XSLT processor to use numeric character references for all non-ASCII characters.  The XSLT processors I have worked with seem by default to prefer decimal to hex NCRs, which can be tedious; you may have better luck, or you may find that you can write your sed to work with the decimal NCRs.

If you are determined to write out a hexadecimal numeric reference come hell or high water, you'll want to read up on 'disable-output-escaping'.  I won't describe how to use it here, partly because I haven't ever needed to use it in earnest, and partly because (as noted above) I don't think it will actually help you with what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found a much easier way to accomplish what I was trying to get with the RTF file anyway.